# RRULE of Icalendar causing time change

Tags: c#, icalendar

I am trying to create a recurrence invite for outlook via c# code.
my working code for single invite is :-

```
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Team Test");
str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", utcStime)); //utcStime is UTC time
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", utcEtime));////utcEtime is UTC time

str.AppendLine("LOCATION:  ");
str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", "Test12345"));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
for (int i = 0; i < msg.To.Count; i++)
{
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[i].DisplayName, msg.To[i].Address));
}
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=\"{0}\":mailto:{1}",
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
```

But when I add a recurrence rule like

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=3"));
```

I receive the mail with different time.
e.g. I use starttime "2016-02-28 13:00"  and endtime "2016-02-28 13:30" converted in UTC and passed it. I received the single invite with same time.
But for recurrence I received the mail with time "07:30 AM" to "08:00 AM".
I tried passing TZID:UTC but it causes error.

I am passing above string to following code

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
sc.Send(msg);  // sc is smtpclient i.e. SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
```

Problem is in the mail received, on calendar recurrence sticks to proper time slots, Please refer the below image where the recurrence meeting slot in calendar is 9 to 930 AM which is correct, but mail contains "When: Occurs every day effective 3/3/2016 until 3/8/2016 from 3:30 AM to 4:00 AM.".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vMbk.png

Comment: Please also post the iCalendar data that's generated by your code.

Comment: @marten sorry for my ignorance, iCalendar data?? I am passing the  stringbuilder with specified rules to alternateview, i updated my code above.

Comment: I meant the actual result of `str.ToString()`. Also please add which time zones all the times you've mentioned refer to (and maybe which time zone you're located in).

Comment: @marten system is on IST, and i am using IST while creating UTC e.g. utcStime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dtStime, countryZone). i am not passing timezone for icalendar. Problem is, it works fine for an invite of single request but time changes for a single invite of recurrence request.